# read id of html objects with cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

I wanna build a single-page layout but i have to use cookies to save the current position on the site because it 'has' to reload the page everytime you click on a link (task for school).

So what I wanted to do is reading the current position of the user (whenever he/she scrolls the page), send that position to a cookie. When the page is reloaded I want to let the user see his previous position and then automatically scroll (using jquery animation) to the position he just clicked on(position of link's anchor)

Can someone help me start building this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myTextInput").bind("keydown keypress mousemove", function() {
  alert("Current position: " + $(this).caret().start);
});
```

get current position of the cursor

for animate to position http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Regards...:)

***[updated]***

use `this.localName` attribute so

```
 $("#myTextInput").bind("keydown keypress mousemove", function() {
      alert("Current position: " + $(this).caret().start);
    aler(this.localName);//this will be div which your is looking at currently
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. This makes clear how to achieve the animation part as well as the position. 

All i want to know now is what a good approach would be for reading which div the user is looking at and how to store that in a cookie.

Comment: @jochemke check udpated